# Is there a way in graph-tool to have an edge have the same color as the source vertex without a color gradient?

Tags: graph-tool

Is there a way in graph-tool to have an edge have the same color as its source vertex without having a gradient? I am referring to a graph such as these examples (https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/inference.html#graph_tool.inference.minimize.minimize_nested_blockmodel_dl) but I'd like to remove the color gradient along the edges and have an edge have the same color as its source vertex.

I am able to assign colors to edges to get rid of the gradient. However, I don't know the color of the source vertex, so I have not found a way to put this to use yet.

Is there a solution for this?

Hopefully, my wording is not confusing, since I am not a native speaker. Have a great day!